# How to compare two strings in same column using Linq?

Tags: c#, linq, sql-server-2008

I have two string which i have to iterate through linq ?

I have status as column and its having row value of

```
     Status
    --------
    Int
    String
    Boolean
    Char
    Float
```

LINQ

```
 var result = from desc in result
 where desc.Status == "string" && desc .Status == "Int"
 select desc ;
```

How to achieve this .. I have tried but it returns empty. If i try with single check its working correctly.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `||` operator

```
where desc.Status == "string" || desc .Status == "Int"
```

Comment: @AravindanSrinivasan, At one point of time you can only have one value. it can be either string or int. Please elaborate

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = from desc in result
             where new[] {"Int","String","Boolean","Char","Float"}.Contains(desc.Status)
                         select desc ;
```